# How to make a cloudy looking planet?

Tags: shaders, textures, procedural-generation, planet

In my game you navigate in space and you can come across planets. You can approach the planet and then land on it.

At first I wanted the planets to be spheres, but then I realised how unpractical this would be. Instead, I decided that when you're in space, the planet would appear as a cloudy looking planet with the color of the planet environment. Then when the player approches the planet, he enters the clouds and get access to the planet which is flat (and in another scene).
The transition between the two scene will be made when entering the athmosphere of the planet, by hiding the view with clouds. You will go from a spherical planet when viewed from space to a flat one when you get close to it.

I don't know how to achieve this. What I would like is an advice on what method could be use to do this. What I'd like is a result that looks like this (for a planet with blue seas and turquoise ground):

[image: wanted result]

Again, I'm not asking for the solution here, I'm asking to I can get to it.

Comment: Do the cloudy planets need to be spherical, or just discs? Do they need to transition smoothly to the flat planet version, or can you cover that with some atmospheric re-entry effects?

Comment: @DMGregory When in space, the planet will be spherical. When entering the athmosphere, the scene will switch to a flat world.

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Generating the spherical cloudy planets, generating the cloudy flat world, transitioning between the two planet modes?

Comment: As I mentionned, I just don't know how to do it and I need to be told what is the best approach for this. Is it with a texture, à shader, particles, generating clouds with perlin noise ? I just have no clue how I should try to do it, and that is my question; how should I do it?

Comment: I'm unlikely to be able to post a full answer in a timely fashion. My current best hunch is to use a perlin/simplex noise to make some initial clouds & then use domain warping to smear them into nice patterns. Similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbrbF38_wUg&t=630s).